# Are private fields visible through related list of a related (public) object?

Tags: apex, security

I created two objects **ObjectVisible** and **ObjectHide**.
**ObjectVisible** has lookup fields to **ObjectHide**.
I set the OWD as follows:
**ObjectVisible**: Public Read,
**ObjectHide**: Private

I used custom code to share **ObjectHide** by creating records in ***ObjectHide__share*** table.
I added the **ObjectVisible** to *standard* Accounts page layout.

The issue is, users that don't have access to the **ObjectHide** record can see the field values through the **ObjectVisible** related list on the Account page.

Is this expected? or some sort of a loophole in object level security? Is there anything else I need to set to enforce the field level security of **ObjectHide** when it's viewed through the related list of **ObjectVisible**?

Example: UserA has access to an **ObjectHidden** record, UserB doesn't. Both users have access to **ObjectVisible** record that has lookup fields to **ObjectHidden** record. **ObjectVisible** related list is on the standard Account page. Both users are able to see the contents of **ObjectVisible** related list, including the values in the lookup fields pointing to **ObjectHidden** (I expected UserB not to be able to see the values). When UserA clicks on an item in the related list pointing to the **HiddenObject** record, it loads the details of the **HiddenObject** record, but when UserB clicks it, it display insufficient privileges (good thing). The problem is why is UserB able to see the **HiddenObject** values through the **VisibleObject** related list?

Comment: Is this a standard page layout or visualforce?

Comment: Standard page layout.

Comment: The users are getting access in another way, what you are describing is not expected and I have never seen it behaving like that.  Use the sharing button on one of those records that should be hidden and find out how are those users getting access. They are either getting access due to having access to a parent record, or they have a permission in their profile such as View All or Modify All.

Comment: Hi Pepe, I check the profiles and they don't have View All/Modify All checked. Also, There's no Master-Detail relationship on the ObjectHidden so it's not inheriting the access permissions from a parent Object. I also checked the Roles for the users I'm using to test and they are all in the same Role so the inherit using role hierarchy is also not the culprit here.

Comment: Are you able to use the Sharing button on one of the records to identify why the user has access?

Comment: Hi Pepe, added an example to the post. I cannot test the Sharing button, the user with no access is unable to see the record details which is a good thing but somehow it can through a related list through another object that has lookup fields to the HiddenObject record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue is.
The ObjectVisible lookup field to the ObjectHidden was being populated using an external integration.
The external intergration used Dataloader to populate the fields and it was signing in as a user with a profile that had access to all data enabled.

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer so it does not keep getting bumped by the bots